# How does angular-ui-bootstrap typeahead templating work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I am trying to add ui.bootstrap-typeahead support to my angular application but I can't seem to wrap my head around one specific problem I'm having. I want to be able to input a number and a unit in one word, say..

```
14tsps
```

Unfortunately I can't figure out a way to get typeahead to treat 'tsps' as a separate word in order to query for it. Even better would be if I could have the dropdown show the number as well. Does anyone with more experience than me have an idea on how to get this to work?

My code so far almost exactly resembles the example code on the site

```
$scope.selected = undefined;
```

and then my HTML

```
<input class="form-control" ng-model="selected"  ui-keypress="{13: 'lineParse()'}" typeahead="word as word.name for word in words | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" >
    <h3>{{selected}}</h3>
```

Another method I've considered is to somehow inject the number into a specified template and then filter the number out of the input before it's processed. Unfortunately I don't know enough about the inner-workings of typeahead for that.

I want to ask a better question here. Can anyone explain to me how ui-typeahead templating works?

Comment: please, show what you tried so far (relevant code)

Comment: It will be _very_ hard to answer this question without a minimal reproduce scenario using http://plnkr.co/

Comment: hey, sorry, I've added some code examples

Comment: Just a suggestion instead of `word in words` use `word in getWords(selected)`. where you create a function __getwords__ which accepts you typeahead model and returns you words. In your function write logic to break input into 2 words